# split NSMutableAttributedString in half category

Tags: ios, nsrange, nsmutableattributedstring

I am having some issues with my category for splitting an NSMutableAttributedString in half it crashes on the `NSMakeRange(...)`

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface NSMutableAttributedString (StringSplit)
- (NSMutableAttributedString *)lastHalfLinesOfAttributedString;
@end


#import "NSAttributedString+StringSplit.h"

@implementation NSMutableAttributedString (StringSplit)

- (NSMutableAttributedString *)lastHalfLinesOfAttributedString
{
    NSLog(@"lastHalfLinesOfAttributedString with length:%d from index: %d", [self length], [self length]/2); 

    NSMutableAttributedString *result = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] init];
    [result insertAttributedString:[self attributedSubstringFromRange:NSMakeRange([self length]/2, [self length]-1)] atIndex:0];

    return result;
}
@end
```

> lastHalfLinesOfAttributedString with length:1020 from index: 510
>   2013-07-02 17:43:16.209 hackers_ssh[36675:c07] *** Terminating app due
>   to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason:
>   'NSConcreteMutableAttributedString attributedSubstringFromRange:: Out
>   of bounds'
>   *** First

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second argument of `NSMakeRange` represents the `length` (counted from the start index in the first argument).

So you want `NSMakeRange([self length] / 2, ([self length] + 1) / 2)`.

By the way, this method of splitting strings only works correctly when there are no combined character sequences or surrogate pairs in the string.

Comment: There is only a danger if there is such a character/pair spanning the `[self length] / 2` index. Such characters/pairs anywhere else only run the risk of the two halves not appearing to be the same length.

Comment: @rmaddy Yes, of course there's no harm done when not splitting a pair. Thanks, rmaddy, for making that clear.